# PHP not responding to given values

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone =) I am trying to make a login for my website, and actually the login is working perfectly. However i decided to add a "first time user" buttom which then asks for the users temporary id. (considering we are in a firm and everyone recieves an id solely this purpose)

If the id is correct (it is in the database) the user preceeds to the "first time profile creation" website, however ... i am having major problems with the interpretation. No matter what combo i try, mysql just throws me out, as if nothing i give is correct.

Here is my simple HTML input + button

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="first_id_check.php" method="POST" >
<p> Please input your given id into the box below </p>
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and here is the php script which should do the work

```
<?php

$contab = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die ("Cannot connect to DB");
$condb = mysql_select_db('info', $contab);

$temp = $_POST['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tempid WHERE Number='$temp'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($result == 1)
{
header("location:first_create.php");
}
else
{
echo "Error, please try again";
sleep(5);
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

"Number" is the name of the colum where the id is stored. But no matter what i enter, i always get rerouted to the "index.php" as if the results always come back 0 >.< How do i fix this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource for select statements. I think you meant to check if the number of rows returned was equal to one:

```
if ($count == 1)
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much, been coding for 8 hours straight, completely missed that amature mistake :D

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is testing $result. Should it be testing $count?

This code is vulnerable to SQL injection - I'd patch that before going too far! Also it's generally worth checking the condition of php functions that return false on failure - all those MySQL functions there fall into that category.

Comment: Jo thanks, been coding for 8 hours straight, i think its time to hit the hay :) Yea the SQL Injection - proof is the next checkpoint on the list :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated. They were replaced by [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Also, you should try to output some debug information first instead of trying to redirect, just for debugging that is. Also, just to debug the mysql, you should put or die(mysql_error()); at the end of each time you use a mysql function. Like this:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you have a major security hole, using direct input from users without any sanitizing of it is very dangerous. It leaves your database open to harmful code. One could very easily with this code take over your entire database with a very simple SQL injection.

You probably want to do this:

```
if ($count == 1)
```

instead of this:

```
if ($result == 1)
```

Also, next time you have such an issue, try to echo the value you test to see if it is what you expect it to be, and try to understand why it isn't if it isn't. As Peter said, var_dump is very useful for this. Same with echo and print_r (the latter is for arrays).

Comment: Yep. People should learn how to debug their code. He should check all lines step by step.`var_dump($result)` then `var_dump($count)` then... check next line. Voila.

Comment: Thank you sir, security is the next checkpoint on the to do list :)